# Building 10.7 Lion apps with Xcode 3.2.6 - Do they work

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

Long time browser, first time asker...

Maybe you can help. I've searched and searched, and seen it asked a few times, but it always turns into a "Xcode 4 sucks" debate.

QUESTION: Do projects built in Xcode 3.2.6 on OSX 10.7, using "Current OS" as base SDK and 10.5 as the target actually work with all versions of OSX?

I had Xcode 3.2.6 on my 10.6 OSX build. I upgraded to Lion, and installed Xcode 4. Xcode 3 was moved to /Developer-3.2.6.

Now some of my old projects don't work in Xcode 4 and I personally prefer 3 (I GIT via command line anyway). But if I build in Xcode 3, it lets me pick "Current OS" as the base SDK, and 10.5 as the target. Am I right in presuming Xcode 3 will now build 10.7, 10.6, and 10.5 apps in 1 binary?

Comment: I think I may have answered my own question. Applications built with 10.6 should automatically work with 10.7. So If I stick with Xcode3, use Current OS as the base, target 10.5 and specify intel only... It should work with 10.5, 10.6, 10.7 all intel only machines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your applications built with Xcode 3.2.6 should run on 10.7. They won't take advantage of any features added in 10.7, like fullscreen windows.

As long as your code doesn't call any methods added in 10.6 or 10.7, your application will run on 10.5 and above if you set the deployment target to 10.5. You don't have to specify Intel only to run on 10.5 through 10.7.